# Python Phone Number Mask

Tags: python, regex

I have two phone numbers and  I need to mask them:

P:`(123)456-1234`

P:`+1(123) 456-1234`

To

P:`***-***-1234`

P:`+*-***-***-1234`

```
import re
m = re.match(r'([0-9\s]+)', line)
print(m.group(1)[-5:-1])
m = re.match(r'([0-9\s-+]+)', line)
print(m.group(1)[-5:-1])
```

I'm getting the result that `m` is `None`.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I have pasted the code, please check @Rishav

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/nY35a8

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because your regex is meant to match a phone number like this `11234561234`

If you just pass strings only containing one phone number through the regex, then it's easy, only two parts do interest you : the one that won't be masked, and the part preceding it.

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = "(.*)(-\d{4})$"
>>> mask_part, public_part = re.match(pat,"+1(123) 456-1234").groups()
>>> print re.sub("\d","*",mask_part) + public_part
+*(***) ***-1234
```

Comment: the brackets are masked by _

Comment: hmmm... do the forms of number you presented are the only forms you really have to deal with ? Also, will you have to deal with foreign numbers ?

Comment: Yes I have to deal with foreign numbers too

Comment: ok, do people filling the information actually have a format to respect, or can they fill the phone number field freely ? Because if they fill it freely, my solution is the simplest.

for instance, in my country, it is common to see this +33(0)1 11 11 11 11, where the "(0)" is just here to remind what the +33 substitute : a zero.

So... what are the complete rules ?

Comment: @Ssravankumar Aditya oh, someone just shared a [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers) to a python library which deals with international phone numbers, that may be your salvation :)